# Distinguish between a user typing in a new URL vs clicking a link in the page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

With the `tabs` permission, an extension can use the `onUpdate` event to listen for a URL update.

However, this does not let the extension determine whether the user changed URL because they clicked a link in the previous page, or whether they manually typed in a new URL, or used a bookmark.

Is there a way to determine whether the user has navigated to a new URL by clicking a link in the previous page? The mechanism would have to work even if they clicked a link which takes them to a different origin.

It would seem quite messy and unreliable to automatically inject a content script into every single web page, add an onClick listener to every link, and continuously monitor the page to check if any new links are added (so that further onClick listeners can be added).

Comment: Use `webNavigation` API and its transitionQualifiers.